# Can I modify string that have already entered when using replace-string command in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, replace, edit

Replacement "A" with "B" will be executed as follow. My question is when I'm in phase 4, can I go back phase 2 and edit "A" again using some commands?

1. M-x replace-string
2. "A"
3. RET
4. "B"
5. RET

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think so, but you can quit and start again.  `C-g`  The function moves in a forward direction . . . once the function is put in motion, the user cannot stop it and say . . . *rewind* please.

Comment: In addition to what @lawlist said, consider using query-replace (e.g., `M-%`).

Comment: You mean query-replace can do it?

Comment: I've replied in my answer, below.

Answer (score 1):

If you are worried about the loss of A and B, because you don't want to type them again then go to step 5 (press RET after B) and then press undo (I see you use `replace-string`, instead of `query-replace`, so you need to undo your changes). This way both inputs are stored in the minibuffer history and when you start the command again you can access them with the up arrow.

Answer (score 1):

1. Consider using `query-replace` instead.

   > You mean query-replace can do it?

   Not sure what you mean by "it", but yes, IMO `query-replace` sounds like what you want.  See the Emacs manual, node `Query Replace`.  Not too that `C-r` lets you pause query-replacing to do whatever you want (e.g. editing) and then resume it again later.
2. Another approach you might consider: [***Icicles***](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/Icicles) [on-demand replacement](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Search-And-Replace).

   It depends what kind of replacing you want to do and how much replacement you want to make. **Icicles** on-demand replacement is designed more as an adjunct to searching than as a systematic replacement technique.

   An advantage is that you do not need to visit each match in turn, and reply saying whether or not you want to replace it.  You are not queried; it is you who decides where you want to perform a replacement.

   And likewise wrt to searching: you need not visit each search hit, in order.  You can visit any search hits that you like, in any order, and cycle among any subsets of them.  You can even sort the search hits in various ways, which affects both ease of access/visibility and cycling order.

Overall, I'd suggest that you start by taking a look at the `query-replace` doc.  If your use case does not, in fact, correspond to what `query-replace` (or **Icicles** replacement) provides, then perhaps elaborate about your use case in your description.

Comment: Sorry It's just grammar mistake. I'm not good at English. But I'll try to explain. What I saying is when I use `M-x query-replace RET "hofe" RET "fuga"`, if I noticed that I misspelled "hofe" during editing "fuga" and want to modify "hofe" to "hoge", there is no way to modify it without using `C-g` and re-enter `M-x query-replace RET "hoge" RET "fuga"` as @lawlist said.

Comment: I see -- you want to change the search pattern, not the replacement pattern. Yes, with `query-replace` and `replace-string`, that is correct: the pattern to match for replacement is fixed at the outset. For **Icicles** search that is true only for the pattern defining the search contexts, not for the pattern defining what to search for within those contexts. But from where you are coming from, it sounds like `C-g` with `q-r` or `r-s` is what you want.